# Umbraco 7 - having trouble with if field

Tags: c#, razor, model, umbraco

I'm pretty new to this and working with a site in Umbraco v7 that already exists.

I am trying to display the word Free when the property alias freeProgram is true.

FreeProgram is already set up with a checkbox on doc type program

It is being used to create filters and it is referenced in a few places

This content is created from a partial template - here's the code (including on of many attempts to create content if freeProgram is true)

```
@model PerformanceSpace.Models.VM_Cards

@{ var imgurl = String.Format("{0}?width={1}&height={2}&mode=crop", Model.imgUrl, Model.doubleCrop ? 700 : 400, Model.doubleCrop ? 400 : Model.smallCard ? 400 : 496); }

    <div class="card-image">
        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.imgUrl))
        {
            <img src="@imgurl" alt="@Model.imgAlt">}
    </div>


    @if (Model.smallCard)
    {
        <div class="py16 px16">
            <h3 class="h6 mb0 card--title" style="color:@Model.txtColour !important">
                @Model.title
            </h3>
        </div> }

    else
    {
        <h3 class="h6 mb0 card__heading">
            <span class="text--hl card--title" style="background-color:@Model.colour;">
                @Model.title
            </span>
        </h3>}

    <div class="card__date mt16" style="color:@Model.txtColour !important">
        <small>@Model.subTitle</small>
    </div>
</a>

@{
    if (!Model.Value<bool>("freeProgram"))
    {
        <p>The Checkbox is not checked!</p>
    }
}
```

Currently this prevents the articles from opening. Tracing things back (remember i am a total noob at this)

I have tried a lot of different syntax and copied if statements that are used in a controller to get the same content

```
@if (model.freeProgram)
{
    <div>free</div>
}
```

here is the model that contains the VMCards class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;

namespace PerformanceSpace.Models
{
    public class VM_RelatedCards
    {
        public string   areaTitle       { get; set; }
        public bool     pastOnly        { get; set; }
        public string   pastURL         { get; set; }
        public string   currentURL      { get; set; }
        public int      displayLimit    { get; set; }
        public string   card1Colour     { get; set; }
        public string   cardTextColour  { get; set; }
        public string   card2Colour     { get; set; }
        public string   card3Colour     { get; set; }
        public bool     altSizes        { get; set; }
        public bool     doubleSizeFirst { get; set; }
        public bool     noCurrentPast   { get; set; }
        public bool     showline        { get; set; }

        public List<VM_Cards> cards { get; set; }


        public VM_RelatedCards()
        {
            init();
        }

        public VM_RelatedCards(IEnumerable<Artist> inputList)
        {
            init(inputList);
        }

        public VM_RelatedCards(IEnumerable<Program> inputList)
        {
            init(inputList);
        }

        public VM_RelatedCards(IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent> inputList)
        {
            init(inputList);
        }

        private void init(IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent> input = null, bool sizeAlternation = false)
        {
            pastOnly        = true;
            displayLimit    = 3;
            cards           = new List<VM_Cards>();
            altSizes        = sizeAlternation;
            doubleSizeFirst = false;
            noCurrentPast   = false;
            showline        = true;

            if (input != null && input.Count() > 0) {
                var T = input.First().GetType();

                if (T == typeof(Artist)) {
                    foreach (Artist item in input) {
                        cards.Add(new VM_Cards(item)); } }
                else if(T == typeof(Program)) {
                    foreach (Program item in input) { 
                        cards.Add(new VM_Cards(item)); } }
                else if(T== typeof(BlogPost)) {
                    foreach(BlogPost item in input) {
                        cards.Add(new VM_Cards(item)); } } } 
        }

        private void init(IEnumerable<Artist> inputList)
        {
            init();

            for (int count = 0; count < inputList.Count(); count++) {
                var item = inputList.ElementAt(count);

                cards.Add(new VM_Cards(item)); }
        }

        private void init(IEnumerable<Program> inputList)
        {
            init();

            foreach (var item in inputList) {
                cards.Add(new VM_Cards(item)); }
        }
    }


    public class VM_Cards
    {
        public string colour    { get; set; }
        public string txtColour { get; set; }
        public string title     { get; set; }
        public string subTitle  { get; set; }
        public string imgUrl    { get; set; }
        public string imgAlt    { get; set; }
        public string linkURL   { get; set; }
        public bool   smallCard { get; set; }
        public string cellClass { get; set; }
        public bool doubleCrop  { get; set; }
        public bool freeProgram  { get; set; }
        public bool onlineProgram { get; set; }

        public VM_Cards()
        {
            smallCard   = false;
            doubleCrop  = false;
            freeProgram = false;

        }

        public VM_Cards(Artist input, bool small = false, string textColour = null)
        {
            this.colour = input.HeadingColours.GetPropertyValue<string>("backgroundColour");
            txtColour   = textColour ?? gFuncs.textColourFromBG(colour);
            title       = input.FirstName + " " + input.LastName;
            subTitle    = input.HeadingText;
            imgUrl      = input.BiographyImage != null ? input.BiographyImage.Url : input.HeadingHeroImage.Url;
            imgAlt      = input.BiographyImage == null ? input.HeadingHeroImage.Name : input.BiographyImage.Name;
            smallCard   = small;
            cellClass   = "mb32";
            linkURL     = input.Url;
            doubleCrop  = false;
        }

        public VM_Cards(Program input, bool small = false, string textColour = null)
        {
            string format   = (input.ProgramDates != null) ? ((List<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent>)input.ProgramDates).ToMultiDate().MaxDate().Date <= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-8) ? "MMM d, yyyy" : "MMM d" : null;
            this.colour     = input.HeadingColours.GetPropertyValue<string>("backgroundColour");
            title           = input.Title;
            subTitle        = input.ProgramDates != null ? input.ProgramDates.ToList().ToMultiDate().MinDate().ToString(format) + ((input.ProgramDates.Count() > 1) ? " - " + input.ProgramDates.ToList().ToMultiDate().MaxDate().ToString(format) : "") : "";
            imgUrl          = input.HeadingHeroImage.Url;
            linkURL         = input.Url;
            smallCard       = small;
            txtColour       = textColour ?? gFuncs.textColourFromBG(colour);
            cellClass       = "mb32";
            doubleCrop      = false;
            freeProgram     = "free";
        }

        public VM_Cards(program input, bool small = false) 
        {
            string format   = input.dateFinish.Year < DateTime.Now.Year ? "MMM d, yyyy" : "MMM d";
            colour          = input.bgColour;
            txtColour       = gFuncs.textColourFromBG(input.fgColour);
            title           = input.heading;


            if (input.dateStart == new DateTime())
            {
                subTitle = "TBC";
            }
            else
            {
                subTitle = input.dateStart.ToString(format) + (input.dateStart.Date != input.dateFinish.Date ? " - " + input.dateFinish.ToString(format) : null);
            }
            imgUrl          = input.img;
            linkURL         = input.url;
            smallCard       = small;
            cellClass       = "mb32";
            doubleCrop      = false;
            freeProgram = "free";
        }

        public VM_Cards(BlogPost input, bool dblCrop = false)
        {
            //string format = "dddd MMMM dd yyyy";
            title           = input.Title;
            //subTitle      = input.CreateDate.ToString(format);
            imgUrl          = input.FeatureImage.Url;
            imgAlt          = input.FeatureImage.Name;
            linkURL         = input.Url;
            colour          = input.CardColour as string;
            txtColour       = gFuncs.textColourFromBG(colour);
            doubleCrop      = dblCrop;
        }
    }
}
```

So from my understanding this appears to be a model that is not created from making a doctype - there are no doctypes called VM

The freeProgam property alias is set originally in the Property model. Here is the property model header and related code.

```
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//   This code was generated by a tool.
//
//    Umbraco.ModelsBuilder v3.0.10.102
//
//   Changes to this file will be lost if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.ModelsBuilder;
using Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Umbraco;

namespace Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels
{
.
.
.


///<summary>
        /// Free Program: Is this a free program?
        ///</summary>
        [ImplementPropertyType("freeProgram")]
        public bool FreeProgram
        {
            get { return this.GetPropertyValue<bool>("freeProgram"); }
        }
```

I think I don't understand the relationship between the model created with modelsbuilder and how to use them in the other namespace (I'm not even really sure what a namespace is but I'm guessing it separates them somehow)

So what I would like to do is to add the word free in the items that have that property alias set. Where am I going wrong? Thanks so much in advance. I'm on a tight deadline as I was told this was a wordpress site and now they can't find anyone else to do it and the site goes live in two days... ergh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that partial template actually renders and the model VM_Cards is populated correctly then you should be able to just do

```
@if(Model.freeProgram) {
   <p>Really free</p>
}
```

Are you getting any error when you try to show the value of that property?

Also, the class VM_Cards has a few different constructors and freeProgram is not initialised in all of them.

Can you show how the model that is passed to the view is being constructed?  There may be a controller (a .cs file), somewhere in your code, that constructs the model that is passed to the view?  Search the code base for the name of the partial view (without .cshtml) and you should be able to find the code that passes VM_Cards to the view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I found out that there was an issue with VS code,  I had to build to make the changes but thought the models builder was doing that for me.  So my code was working!!